# RabbitMQ + Event Driven architecture

Tags: node.js, architecture, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, event-driven

I am a newbee in Event Driven architecture. Try to implement it with the usage of microservices + `RabbitMQ`. So, I have the following problem:

1. There are 3 microservices
2. 1st one stores some data, 2 other store data related to data from 1st (it means that in db schema they have field `<data_from_1st_ms>ID`)
3. When I update instance from 1st ms then I want to automatically update data in 2nd and 3rd microservice. It means I want to add event to RabbitMQ called `dataUpdated` with `dataId` and then two my microservices got this message and update internal data.

As I get, I can use [RabbitMQ exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html). Am I correct that in my case I should create exchange with name `data-updated` then I should create 2 queues - `update-data-2-ms` and `update-data-3-ms` and then bind this 2 queues to exchange. Then I should send message with `dataId` to exchange `data-updated` after every update of data. Please, correct me if I'm mistaken.

P.S. And is it correct that every new event (like dataDeleted, dataAdded, etc.) creates new exchange in `rabbit`?

Comment: For a standard fanout (to different consumer domains), one exchange bound to multiple queues is correct. The queues can be considered to be “part of” each receiving service, not the originator.

Comment: Not sure whether rabbitMQ support multiple consumers for multiple producers means queue independently listened by the consumer like in Kafka. If it is present there, then one queue will be sufficient also for another type of message(add,delete,update), you don't need to create a separate queue, while publish you can add the type of message from an operation and by that type, you can distinguish the message. So managing so many queue is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The fanout exchange you mentioned is suitable for applying the observer pattern. It is also possible to utilize the `topic exchange` and separate the `routing_key` for each type of event to manage the queue that will receive chosen `update, add, or delete` event as instructed [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html).

However, if you use fanout exchange I don't recommend for you to separate the exchange for update, add, and delete events. The order of the event that consumed might change due to the pending queue. For example, the outgoing event in order is `create B -> create A -> update A`. If you separate the queue for each action, `create A` event might still be waiting for `create B` event to complete its process while `update A` event already consumed, making an update attempt to non-existent object A and eventually the object A is not updated.